# Php how to display the video?

Tags: php

I have a code and I would like to edit it so that the video uploaded shows up on my webpage and is then stored in the upload folder.
**Code:**

```
<?php
 $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
 $allowType = array("video/mp4","audio/mp3","audio/wma","image/png","image/gif","image/jpeg");
 $maxSize = 20000000000000;
 $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $pathToUpload = 'upload/';

 if( in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowType) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] <= $maxSize)
 {
          if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
     {
         echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
     }
     else 
     {
         echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
         echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
         echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
         echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

         if (file_exists($pathToUpload . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
         {
             echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
         }
         else
         {
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $pathToUpload . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
             echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
         }
     }
 }
 else
 {
     echo "Invalid file";
 }
```

I am not looking for someone to give me the code but to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

At the point where the video is moved and you are echo'ing its location:

```
"Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

instead of echo'ing where it's stored you could add it to a videos table of some sort:

```
$videoLocation = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
// now insert $videoLocation into a database table
//so you can fetch it on whatever page you feel like
```